# JAR file with non UTF-8 charset

Tags: java, jar, character-encoding

In Java, parsing a ZIP archive using a specified charset can be done by using the `ZipFile(File, Charset)` constructor for instance.

JarFile (in the util package) inherits from ZipFile, but does not offer ways to use a charset other than UTF-8. I need to parse Jar files that contain strings not encoded with UTF-8. What would be the cleanest workaround to do this?

(I have thought of using reflection to modify the private field `ZipFile.zc` right after JarFile() constructor returns, but this solution is not robust and Oracle-specific.)

Comment: I would interpret that as a strong indication that jar filed MUST use UTF-8. Otherwise, since JarFile won't be able to read the names correctly, your jar file won't be usable.

Comment: @JB: that might be it... I am using JarFile to read APK files, which are really close to JAR files (manifest, signed entries, certificates, etc.) but APKs may allow the encoding of file entries in any charset, just like ZIP file allows. Any thoughts on a portable workaround? (possibly avoiding reflection)

Answer (score 1):

The Charset parameter is according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#ZipFile(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) only used "*to decode the ZIP entry name and comment*". Therefore it is totally irrelevant for you. When you read a file from a ZipFile or Jar you are getting an InputStream with is agnostic regarding the used charset.

Therefore you have to apply the correct charset when converting the byte array based InputStream to a chaaracter based reader, e.g. by using an [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

Edit:
In case we are talking about the file-names in the ZIP file you should be able to create a parallel ZipFile instance on the same file. Use `JarFile.getName()` for reading out the jar file path.

Comment: This is exactly my point: some entry names cannot be read because they are not encoded using UTF-8. It has nothing to do with the entries' contents.